# How can I use a VPN to protect an EC2 instance so that only my devs can access it

Tags: amazon-ec2, vpn, amazon-web-services

I have a dev EC2 instance and I would like to use a VPN (ideally provided by AWS) so that only my web devs could access the website on port 80

Is this What virtual private connect is for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put it in an [Amazon Virtual Private Cloud](http://aws.amazon.com/vpc/), or just limit the EC2 instance's security group to port 80 and your web devs' IP addresses.

Comment: Care to expand on what that is and how it would help?

Comment: Done, 'though about five seconds on Google would reveal everything you need to know.

Answer (score 0):

Set up OpenVPN and make apache only listen on the VPN interface: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/bind.html.